# Number of arrangements on circle

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following problem.

''12 points are marked on the circumference of a circle and labelled with integers from 1 to 12. Find the number of possible arrangements such that points labelled with 3, 6, 9, 12 are separated one by one.''

The similar problem with 8 points instead of 12 can be solved quite easily, but I can not adapt the method used in that case for the problem stated above.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does one by one mean?

Comment: The ants go marching one by one, to another question that fun...

Comment: I think  ''separated one by one'' means that there must be at least one point between any two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can place $12$ to set the orientation of the circle.  Now how many ways can you choose the spots that will hold $3,6,9?$.  How many ways to arrange them in those spots?  How many ways to arrange the rest of the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I assume 'separated one by one' means that there should be one in between.  Note that this introduces a rotational asymmetry (because you get a sequence of fice successive numbers that are not one of $3,6,9,12$), and so there is no need to worry about rotational symmetry like there was for the case with $8$ total numbers.

Therefore, you can just calculate the number of ways to order the $3,6,9,12$ (which is $4!$), and multiply that by the number of ways to place the others among them (which is $8!$). So: $4!8!$

Answer (score 0):

Can check in the link your question I think is similar to question no.4 or 5 in the distribution of objects.

https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/distribution-of-identical-objects-into-distinct-groups/